Problems with referencing figures in wrapfigure
When trying to reference figures within a wrapfigure environment, the cref returns the section the figure is in instead of the actual figure.
I would like the cref to return something like figure 1.1 instead of the chapter/section/subsection the figure is in.
My MWE
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}\label{sec:testsection}
test test\\
        \begin{wrapfigure}[12]{r}{0.3\textwidth}\label{fig:testfigure}
            \begin{center}
                \vspace*{-23pt}
                \includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]{includes/figures/test.png}
            \end{center}
        \end{wrapfigure}
\\
test test test \cref{fig:testfigure}

\end{document}


If your figure doesn't have a caption, what number should the cross-reference print?

Not really related, but your usage of \\  looks wrong (but hard to say from a small MWE like this).

A \label always references the last stepped reference counter. Inside your wrapfigure environment nothing steps the figure counter so the \section is referenced. You need to put a \caption there.1
It is best if you get used to put \label inside the mandatory argument of \section, \caption etc. (it works there just as you intend it to, is less prone to cause spacing issues, and you don't accidentally put it in the wrong place where it references the wrong stuff).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction\label{sec:testsection}}

        \begin{wrapfigure}[12]{r}{0.3\textwidth}
            \begin{center}
                \vspace*{-23pt}
                \includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
                \caption{A duck\label{fig:testfigure}}
            \end{center}
        \end{wrapfigure}
test test
test test test \cref{fig:testfigure}

\end{document}


1 Well, technically any counter can be a reference counter, more correct would be to say the \label references the last \refstepcounter.
